# Message center in Android

Tags: android

The Android app I'm developing interacts with a remote machine that may returns errors or have problems.

Currently I'm showing ugly popups at every warning or blocking error, but I wanted some sort of centralized notification center. I don't want to use normal Android notifications since the user has to leave the application.

I wanted some sort of badge indicating the number or warnings/errors that have happened until now and something that can resume what happened (like a listview with all the errors happened).

I'm wondering if that's the best approach to deal with this type of problem and/or if there are any public library out there that might solve my problem.

I've seen that Snackbar might be helpful for non blocking errors, and there are a lot of badge libraries, but still nothing for the "notification center".

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to "notify" users about progress, issues and other important messages. The logical place to do so would be using a `Notification`. You can also provide buttons in the notification that directs the user to conflict resolution.

[Documentation about Notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

[Official Documentation for creating Notifications](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html).

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!");
```

Make sure that you are certain that your user actually cares about these messages (errors). Provide them a way to ignore them. Usually in the App settings.

Comment: the problem is that we have the standard notifications blocked via the launcher because we didn't want the basic user to interact with the settings. Wondering if you can keep the settings blocked and still get the notifications.